# Is there any graphical-based user interface for Linux in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, gui

Linux can launch a desktop environment with the standard graphical interface familiar to most people.

It also has a terminal in which you can use a command-line interface.

I recently discovered a graphical framework for terminal applications: https://vue-termui.dev/

I would like to know if there is any graphical terminal application which provides the entire interface to your system; like what a desktop environment is. That is, when you launch it, it provides graphical access to things like files or applications, but inside the terminal.

This is because I use terminals very much on an iPhone and it would be really nice to have the capabilities of Linux but a graphical interface that supports mouse/touch.

Comment: Maybe Emacs can serve that role because I recently read somebody saying “You can do basically anything from Emacs”.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But you may be able to find a better interface for your iPhone to interact with your server. For example VNC Viewer or Remote Desktop both offer access to a graphical desktop (WIMP) with standard GUI devices such as mouse (finger).

Answer (score 0):

tmux is a good jumping-off point to craft one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPWEX2446B4

Add in midnight commander... and some weather stuff...

Comment: "weather stuff"?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/461247)